# C# increase the size of reading binary data

Tags: c#

I am using the below code from [Jon Skeet's article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html). Of late, the binary data that needs to be processed has grown multi-fold. The binary data size file size that I am trying to import is ~ 900 mb almost 1 gb. How do I increase the memory stream size.

```
public static byte[] ReadFully (Stream stream)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        while (true)
        {
            int read = stream.Read (buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            if (read <= 0)
                return ms.ToArray();
            ms.Write (buffer, 0, read);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A stream doesn't take up memory. The byte array, of which you are making with `ms.ToArray()`, is taking up memory. Don't return a `byte[]` if you don't want _all_ of the file data loaded into memory.

Comment: You want to store almost 1 GB in memory? Why? Don't!

Comment: That solution reads the entire file into memory.  It sounds like you should explore a solution where you don't have to have the entire file in memory.

Comment: I believe you may be using the *ReadFully* method incorrectly. Why do you need to read the whole stream into an array to process it? The *Stream* class already offers seeking.

Comment: the memorystream will automatically grow, it will run out of memory eventually tho. Look at this - a chunked MemoryStream class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203121/chunked-memorystream

Answer (score 0):

Your method returns a byte array, which means it will return *all* of the data in the file. Your *entire* file will be loaded into memory.

If that is what you want to do, then simply use the built in File methods:

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(string path);
string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(string path);
```

If you don't want to load the entire file into memory, take advantage of your `Stream`

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("path", FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    // do stuff with 'line' here, or use one of the other
    // StreamReader methods.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to increase the size of [MemoryStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ad966f9s(v=vs.110).aspx) - by default it expands to fit the contents.

Apparently there can be [problems with memory fragmentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595061/outofmemoryexception-while-populating-memorystream-256mb-allocation-on-16gb-sys), but you can pre-allocate memory to avoid them:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(1024 * 1024 * 1024))  // initial capacity 1GB
{
}
```

In my opinion 1GB should be no big deal these days, but it's probably better to process the data in chunks if possible. That is what Streams are designed for.