# Troubles with time jump while processing iterations

Tags: c#

I have large application that processes big data (about 5 000 000 bytes) every second and send information to other service in byte compressed format.

I use protobuf serialization to bytes and LZ4 for compression.

Here is my code:

```
    internal static byte[] ConvertToBytes(object data)
    {
        using (var uncompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            SerializerModel.Serialize(uncompressedStream, data);

            if (_typesToCompress.Contains(data.GetType()))
                using (var compressedStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    var head = DateTime.Now;

                    using (var lz4 = new LZ4Stream(compressedStream, LZ4StreamMode.Compress, LZ4StreamFlags.IsolateInnerStream))
                        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(lz4))
                            writer.Write(uncompressedStream.ToArray());

                    if (uncompressedStream.Length > 0)
                        LogService.Enqueue(
                            $"Сжато {uncompressedStream.Length - compressedStream.Length} байт ({100 - 100.0 * compressedStream.Length / uncompressedStream.Length:0.0}% от объема) {data.GetType().Name} за {(DateTime.Now - head).TotalMilliseconds:0.0} мс",
                            LogTextType.Warning);
                    return compressedStream.ToArray();
                }
            return uncompressedStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

It works fine and I spend around 50 ms for this operation every second.

But sometimes (about each 10 iterations) I can see big time jump (300-500 ms) that happen in other parts of my code but more often in this part during convert or compression. Below is the schedule with emissions that i watch.

[plot with time jumps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSCkk.png)

I think it's associated with LOH but not sure. Please, help me to resolve this problem!

Comment: Could the size of the array be causing the Jump in time?

Comment: Maybe it's related to garbage collection?  You're creating a new, large array of bytes in each iteration instead of reusing previously allocated space.  That's going to eat up memory very quickly.

Comment: Yeah, cleaning up the LOH (which holds objects >85kb) will require a full Gen3 collection (use PerfMon to figure this out), and there isn't much you can do about that unless you start managing your own memory (and, looking at your code, I really can't imagine how you'd do that).  Is there any point in your processing where you are idle enough to afford the collection?  If so, you could preemptively schedule it then.  You can also play games with the GC's LatencyModes and with `GCSettings.LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode`.

Comment: Also, if you have a region of code where timing is critical, you can use `GC.TryStartNoGCRegion` to mark your code in a way that GC operations should not happen during those critical parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I spent some hours playing with GC options and didn't achieve a goal. But finally I found the solution that suiting for me.

It's [ChunkedMemoryStream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25176219/10474447). I took this code and added property that return blocks of bytes (<85kb).

```
    public IEnumerable<byte[]> Chunks
    {
        get
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < _chunks.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                yield return _chunks[i];
            }
            var last = new byte[_lastChunkPos];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(_chunks[_chunks.Count - 1], 0, last, 0, _lastChunkPos);
            yield return last;
        }
    }
```

Then I modified my method:

```
    internal static byte[] ConvertToBytes(object data)
    {
        using (var uncompressedStream = new ChunkedMemoryStream())
        {
            SerializerModel.Serialize(uncompressedStream, data);
            if (_typesToCompress.Contains(data.GetType()))
                using (var compressedStream = new ChunkedMemoryStream())
                {
                    var head = DateTime.Now;
                    using (var lz4 = new LZ4Stream(compressedStream, LZ4StreamMode.Compress, LZ4StreamFlags.IsolateInnerStream))
                    using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(lz4))
                    {
                        foreach (var chunk in uncompressedStream.Chunks)
                        {
                            writer.Write(chunk);
                        }
                    }

                    if (uncompressedStream.Length > 0)
                        LogService.Enqueue(
                            $"Сжато {uncompressedStream.Length - compressedStream.Length} байт ({100 - 100.0 * compressedStream.Length / uncompressedStream.Length:0.0}% от объема) {data.GetType().Name} за {(DateTime.Now - head).TotalMilliseconds:0.0} мс",
                            LogTextType.Warning);
                    return compressedStream.ToArray();
                }
            return uncompressedStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Finally, number of time jumps greatly reduced. Now they occur once or twice per two minutes and it's OK for me)